# Como obter o ArrayList da ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview

Tenho uma tela na minha aplicação com vários campos, spinners e uma listview, um dos spinner é de produtos. 
Quando seleciono um produto no spinner e clico em um botão chamado adicionar, o aplicativo popula esta listview com o id, nome, quantidade e preço do produto.

Até aí está tudo funcionando perfeitamente, mas quando clico no botão Concluir venda, tenho que fazer os inserts com nome do cliente, os produtos etc... etc..., não estou conseguindo fazer isto.

Fiz de várias formas mas nenhuma deu certo.
Para colocar os produtos na listview estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

Na Classe PedidoProdutoActivit eu recupero o spinner acesso o id do item selecionado dentro do spinner depois faço uma consulta na tabela de produtos utilizando este id e atribuo as informações em variaveis:

```
ListView lstpro = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lsProdutos);
            EditText eqtd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtQuantidade);
            Spinner spProd = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spProduto);
            SQLiteCursor dados = (SQLiteCursor) spProd.getAdapter().getItem(spProd.getSelectedItemPosition());

            final BancoController crud = new BancoController(getBaseContext());
            final Cursor cursor = crud.carregaDadosByIdProd(dados.getInt(0));

            quant = String.valueOf(eqtd.getText());
            dpreco = dados.getDouble(2);

            iqtd = Integer.parseInt(quant);
            dtotal = dpreco * iqtd;

            stotal = String.valueOf(dtotal);

            novoId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CriaBanco.getProId()));
            novaDescricao = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CriaBanco.getProDescricao()));
            novoPreco = stotal;
            novaQtd = quant;
```

depois criei uma classe Produtos para armazenar o valor destas variaveis:

```
public class Produtos {

private int linha;
private String  id;
private String descricao;
private String quantidade;
private String  preco;

public Produtos(int linha){
    this.linha = linha;
}

public Produtos(String id, String descricao, String quantidade, String preco){
    this.id = id;
    this.descricao = descricao;
    this.quantidade = quantidade;
    this.preco = preco;
}

public String getId(){
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id){
    this.id = id;
}

public String getPreco() {
    return preco;
}

public void setPreco(String preco) {
    this.preco = preco;
}

public String getQuantidade() {
    return quantidade;
}

public void setQuantidade(String quantidade) {
    this.quantidade = quantidade;
}

public String getDescricao() {
    return descricao;
}

public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
    this.descricao = descricao;
}

public int getLinha() {
    return linha;
}

public void setLinha(int linha) {
    this.linha = linha;
}
```

}

depois criei uma classe adapter para ter acesso ao modelo da listview:

```
public class ProdutosAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private LayoutInflater prodInf;
private ArrayList<Produtos> produtos;

public ProdutosAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Produtos> produtos){
    this.produtos = produtos;

    prodInf = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return produtos.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    Produtos produto = produtos.get(position);
    return produtos.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    Produtos produto = produtos.get(position);
    view = prodInf.inflate(R.layout.pedido_produto_modelo, null);

    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txlpId)).setText(produto.getId());
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txlpDescricao)).setText(produto.getDescricao());
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txlpqtd)).setText(produto.getQuantidade());
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txlpPreco)).setText(produto.getPreco());

    return view;
}
```

}

e então fiz o resto em PedidoProdutoActivity para que os produtos fossem colocados na listview

```
Produtos item = new Produtos(novoId, novaDescricao, novaQtd, novoPreco);

            produtos.add(item);

            produtosAdapter = new ProdutosAdapter(getBaseContext(), produtos);

            lstpro.setAdapter(produtosAdapter);
```

Isso está funcionando perfeitamente, o problema é que não estou conseguindo recuperar as informações entro da listview para fazer os inserts necessários.

Tentei acessar de várias formas com SQLCursor, Cursor etc...

o que mais funcionou até agora foi da seguinte forma:

```
Button confirma = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConfirmar);
    confirma.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ListView lstprod = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lsProdutos);

            final BancoController crud = new BancoController(getBaseContext());
            crud.op = 2;

            int linhas = lstprod.getCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < linhas; i++ ){
                Produtos linha = new Produtos(i);


                String id = linha.getId();
                String descricao = linha.getDescricao();
                String qtd = linha.getQuantidade();
                String preco = linha.getPreco();
            }
        }
    });
```

o problema é que vem tudo null quando é executado, alguém tem alguma dica que possa me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No *ProdutosAdapter* crie um método que retorne a lista de produtos:

```
public ArrayList<Produtos> getProdutos(){
    return produtos;
}
```

No `onClick()` do botão utilize-a da seguinte forma:

```
Button confirma = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConfirmar);
confirma.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        //Se tiver aqui acesso ao produtosAdapter, estas duas linhas não são necessárias
        ListView lstprod = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lsProdutos);
        ProdutosAdapter produtosAdapter = lstprod.getAdapter();

        final BancoController crud = new BancoController(getBaseContext());
        crud.op = 2;

        ArrayList<Produtos> produtos = produtosAdapter.getProdutos();
        int linhas = produtos.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < linhas; i++ ){

            Produtos linha = produtos.get(i);
            String id = linha.getId();
            String descricao = linha.getDescricao();
            String qtd = linha.getQuantidade();
            String preco = linha.getPreco();
        }
    }
});
```

Nota: A sua classe Produtos deveria chamar-se Produto

Comment: Funcionou, nossa era bem simples, mas é complicado estar aprendendo e não achar nenhum material sobre algo, muito obrigado mesmo